# HTML - JS Almaceno un dato en una variable y me muestra que la variable esta nula,

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario pero cuando ingresa la contrasena, el resultado me lo muestra "null". Me podrian ayudar? Gracias!!

```
<script>
    function recibirDatos() {
        let correo = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
        document.write("Correo: " + correo);
        
        let pass = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1");
        document.write("Password: " + pass);
    } </script>

    <form>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="recibirDatos();">
    </form>
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como recuperar la contrasena y que me imprima la contrasena ingresada?

Comment: NOTA: El .value al final de getElementById no hace ninguna diferencia.

Comment: el problema esta cuando haces document.write. Si mostras los datos dentro de elementos html en lugar de hacer document.write te va a andar todo sin problemas. Y si, vas a necesitar poner el .value del final

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que obtienes el valor del e-mail con

```
document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
```

deberias poner en el password:

```
document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
```

en el código que muestras en la variable `pass` simplemente estas tomando el objeto, no su value.

```
<script>
    function recibirDatos() {
        let correo = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
        document.write("Correo: " + correo);
        
        let pass = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
        document.write("Password: " + pass);
    } </script>

    <form>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="recibirDatos();">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el script, en el pass falta agregar el .value cuando capturas.

Esta línea: (Aquí se captura el elemento)

```
let pass = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1");
```

Debería quedar así: (Aquí se captura el valor del elemento)

```
 let pass = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
```

También hay que corregir algo al momento de realizar 2 document.write.

Quedaría de la siguiente manera completo.

```
<script>
  function recibirDatos() {
    let correo = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value;
    let pass = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1").value;
    document.write("Correo: " + correo," Password: " + pass);
  }
</script>
```

Sería un único document.write pasando 2 expresiones.

Adjunto links a documentación.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write